# What's the difference between for w in words[:] and for w in words[] in Python

Tags: python

①

```
words = ['Hello','Python','Java']

for item in words:
    if len(item) > 4:
        words.insert(0,item)
```

②

```
words = ['Hello','Python','Java']

for item in words[:]:
    if len(item) > 4:
        words.insert(0,item)
```

The ① source can't run successfully.
But the ②　can run successfully.
what's the difference between the source.
Can you tell me why?

Comment: Well, `words[]` isn't valid Python.

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking. 1 and 2 are different, and 1 is not valid syntax, so why would you even ask about it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure he meant the first one to read "for item in words:"

Comment: I am very sorry that I make a mistake,the① is "for item in words", I know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working off the assumption that you meant your first one to read `for item in words:`.

`words[:]` makes a copy of the list words and then iterates over that copy. Then, your code modifies the original list.

The first one iterates over the original list and modifies the list at the same time, so it results in an infinite loop, where you keep adding to the list as you're iterating over it.

Comment: Yes,I make a mistake.As you say,The first one is for item in words:.Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

First let us see what they do by tracing out their iterations,

```
words = ['Hello','Python','Java']

for item in words:
    if len(item) > 4:
        words.insert(0,item)
```

words initially contains ['Hello','Python','Java'],
then after the first two iterations the if condition fails.

But in the third iteration the condition is true and the new list will be as, ['Java','Hello','Python','Java'] but the current index in the list (or the current element pointing) is on 'Python' so it increment the index then goes for the index =3 where it finds 'Java' again and inserts it into the same list making the list as, ['Java','Java','Hello','Python','Java'].

This way it runs through infinite loops by executing the same element again and again.

Coming for the second,

```
words = ['Hello','Python','Java']
for item in words[:]:
    if len(item) > 4:
        words.insert(0,item)
```

The slice, words[:] returns a list containing the values ['Hello','Python','Java'] but not referencing the words list to iterate over, therefore any insertions, deletions or operations performed on the original words list would not affect the list it iterates on,
so just three iterations and final words list will be ['Java','Hello','Python','Java'].

Answer (score 0):

```
['Python', 'Hello', 'Hello', 'Python', 'Java']
```

This will be the output of the second code.

In the first iteration Hello will satisfy condition and will be at 0th position.

For second iteration Python will satisfy condition and will be at 0th position.

Because of slicing original reference index is not changed in loop and therefore in third iteration condition fails and you get this type of output.

```
['Python', 'Hello', 'Hello', 'Python', 'Java']
```

Ihile in first case the index reference used in loop will continuously access new index from output list resulting in infinite loop.